# Resize program works for some and not others

Tags: c, computer-science, cs50

So the problem is supposed to take 3 arguments (factor, infile and outfile). The factor is a positive integer from 1 - 100. The program then is suppose to resize the infile image. If the factor is 1: produce the same image. If the factor is 2: produce an image twice as big. And so on. The output image should be written to the outfile.

Currently my program does this successfully for some images and only on certain scale factors.

When I run it through my course's IDE check program for this question, the results I receive are:

:) resize.c and bmp.h exist.
:) resize.c compiles.
:) doesn't resize small.bmp when n is 1
:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 2
Byte 34 of pixel data doesn't match. Expected 0xff, not 0x00

:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 3
Byte 48 of pixel data doesn't match. Expected 0xff, not 0x00

:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 4
Byte 62 of pixel data doesn't match. Expected 0xff, not 0x00

:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 5
Byte 80 of pixel data doesn't match. Expected 0xff, not 0x00

:) resizes large.bmp correctly when n is 2
:) resizes smiley.bmp correctly when n is 2

```
// Copies a BMP file and resizes it

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bmp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize factor infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Check argument 1 to see if integer within acceptable range
    int factor = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (factor <= 0 || factor > 100)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Must be a positive integer greater than 0 and equal or less than 100\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[2];
    char *outfile = argv[3];

    // open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 3;
    }


    // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf_New;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);
    bf_New = bf;

    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi_New;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);
    bi_New = bi;

    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    // set new height and width of BMP
    bi_New.biHeight = bi.biHeight * factor;
    bi_New.biWidth = bi.biWidth * factor;

    // calculate padding for old file and new file
    int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
    int padding_New = (4 - (bi_New.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    // set the file size for the new file
    bi_New.biSizeImage = (bi_New.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + padding_New) * abs(bi_New.biHeight);
    bf_New.bfSize = bi_New.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);


    // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bf_New, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi_New, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
        {
            // itterate factor times
            for (int k = 0; k < factor; k++)
            {
                // iterate over pixels in scanline
                for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
                {
                    // temporary storage
                    RGBTRIPLE triple;

                    // read RGB triple from infile
                    fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

                    // iterate over horizontal pixels
                    for (int l = 0; l < factor; l++)
                    {
                        // write RGB triple to outfile iterate the same pixel by factor times
                        fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
                    }
                }

                // skip over padding, if any
                fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

                // add new padding
                for (int m = 0; m < padding_New; m++)
                {
                    fputc(0x00, outptr);
                }

                // seek back to the beginning of row in input file, but not after iteration of printing
                if (k + 1 < factor )
                {
                    fseek(inptr, -(bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)), SEEK_CUR);
                }
            }
        }

    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // close outfile
    fclose(outptr);

    // success
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're handling the input padding correctly. To debug your input and output padding, create an image with an odd width, like 15. Then scale by an odd number, like 3. Then simply look at the output image with a viewer, and see if it looks right.

Answer (score 1):

I found the place where the mistake is i hope.. after saving first line of pixels, u seek padding width to new position.. then seek back width* size of the triple, which doesn't include padding.. i think u can separate loop like this.. for factor -1 times u seek back, for what u hv printed without padding..  for the last time u seek forward with padding.. so that you are ready to start new line...